# Android Studio debugger disconnects instead of breaking...but only on certain crashes

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I have a certain crash that is happening in my app that causes Android Studio to disconnect my device from the debugger instead of stopping at a breakpoint. Does anyone know how to make it break at the crash instead of disconnect?

To be clear: the other 99.9% of the time breakpoints work - every breakpoint I put in the app breaks. But when the code runs past a certain line in a 3rd party library the app crashes and it disconnects the debugger instead. It happens across multiple installations and I've had this issue randomly on a variety of bugs over months of development across different machines and devices and versions of Android Studio. I've been able to work through it before with the error messages etc but this time there aren't any helpful error messages in the console and I'm a bit stuck.

It doesn't matter if I have all exception breakpoints on or not. I am unable to find any other questions that deal with only certain exceptions disconnecting the device (or emulator) from the debugger. Has anyone else been able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix my issue here. It turns out that rolling back the NDK version from the current (at time of writing) v 13b back to 11c fixes the crash. So I don't know a lot of the "why" this fixed the problem other than what a friend mentioned about there being a bug in the newest version, which caused me to roll back the NDK.

Not the comprehensive answer I was hoping for but it's good enough for my current needs. If anyone has a better explanation, I'd love to understand the "why" better. Or if someone has an actual solution, I'd be even more thrilled.